# Can I get the final HTML page ( after executing the scripts ) with JSoup, HtmlUnit or anything at all?

Tags: jsoup, htmlunit

So I'm trying to simulate clicking on this button:

```
<input class="btn" value="Say thanks!" onclick="say_thanks(546810)" id="thanks_button" type="button">
```

And I'm trying to do it while the program is in the background. Otherwise, I could just use selenium, but I don't want a foreground program to use my mouse and focus the browser it's using. I've tried finding any workaround, but no luck so far.
Tried simulating with HtmlUnit like this:

```
DomElement button = page.getFirstByXPath("//input[@value='Say thanks!']");
HtmlPage newPage = button.click();
```

But I keep getting this error, no matter the type of selector I'm using ( tried with anchors, byId, byClass etc ):

```
SEVERE: runtimeError: message=[An invalid or illegal selector was specified (selector: '*,:x' error: Invalid selector: *:x).] sourceName=[https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js] line=[2] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
```

I am open to any suggestion, regardless of the tools required ( if there's any I'm not using already ).

BIG EDIT:
So I've double checked how the page looks in plain text after I parse it with JSoup, and the actual button is nowhere to be found. There's some JQuery script which, I guess, would trigger the button to appear ( it will appear only if I didn't press it ever before ) in the final HTML document. Now I would need to evaluate that script to get the final HTML and, as I've seen on the internet, HtmlUnit should do that, but doesn't.

I've tried JSoup, HtmlUnit, HttpClient and Jaunt but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

There is a misunderstanding from your side:

If

```
DomElement button = page.getFirstByXPath("//input[@value='Say thanks!']");
```

failed, you would get a plain java exception and not a log entry (btw. your are using an xpath selector but the log entry is about css selectors).

To make you more comfortable you can add the line

```
System.out.println(button.asXml())
```

after the selection and you will see HtmlUnit has found your input element.

The log entry is the result of some javascript execution started after you have clicked the button (and because you have clicked the button).

This kind of message is really common when using HtmlUnit with pages build using jQuery or other frameworks. These frameworks are using invalid css selectors to check the features of your browser. HtmlUnit will report this, but the javascript will continue to work. Usually this is a warning message in the context of HtmlUnit containing the severe error message as reason/detail.

Outside of this calling the click() method is the correct way to simulate clicking the button.

Comment: Actually, there's a NullPointerException as well, either if I'm trying to click it or just print what you've said. Sorry that I forgot about that. So it does not click on it, hence not executing that action.

Comment: Sounds like getFirst  does not found anything. Call Page.asXml first and check the output.